# Dependency needs to be configured differently based on parent type requested in StructureMap

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

We're using StructureMap and are trying to figure out how to achieve the following.

We have 2 interfaces : 
 ICat, IDog

For ICat we need to use and instance of Cat. The Cat constructor takes an instance of ISound.

For IDog we need to use and instance of Dog. The Dog constructor also takes an instance of ISound.

ISound has one implementation AnimalSound.

So far so good. This part we can do in structure map quite easily.

The problem arises now with AnimalSound. AnimalSound has a constructor which can be initialized with a LoudSound or a SoftSound. (LoudSound and SoftSound share the same interface IVolume)

We want all Cats to be given an AnimalSound that was constructed with SoftSound, and all Dogs to be constructed with AnimalSound that was constructed with LoudSound.

Short of changing the design to use a Factory, is there a way to configure this decoratively in StructureMap  (we're using 2.6.4.1)

Answer (score 1):

Using named instances you can do this:

```
For<ISound>().Add<AnimalSound>().Ctor<IVolume>().Is<LoudSound>().Named("Loud");
For<ISound>().Add<AnimalSound>().Ctor<IVolume>().Is<SoftSound>().Named("Soft");
For<ICat>().Use<Cat>().Ctor<ISound>().Named("Soft");
For<IDog>().Use<Dog>().Ctor<ISound>().Named("Loud");
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that `ICat` and `IDog` are the actual names of interfaces in your application, so I can't really feedback on that design. However, in general I would say that there is ambiguity in your design that leads you to this situation. Instead of complicating your DI configuration, you would urge you to take a good look at the design and look if it shouldn't be fixed.